# Microsoft Access: Multi-valued field is not valid in the expression

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In **Access** I created two tables. One being an input dataset and one being an enrichment table to the input set. In the enrichment table I created multi-valued fields. The reason why I created these fields is in the fact that a combination of the selected multi-valued fields are to be rolling up to a specific ID number (named the *LCR DA 73 Main*). I have tried connecting the tables but, unfortunately get the following error:

"The multi-valued field .............is not valid in the expression ..........."

```
The initial database = LM_AAVNL_P10_2016_New
The enrichment table = C73_Outflow
The expression = RCOA_Sel: 
IIf([C73_Outflow]![Reporting CoA_New]=[LM_AAVNL_P10_2016_New]![Reporting CoA];"Y";"N")
```

[Click here to see the Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsRGp.jpg)

[Click here to see the multi-valued table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1iO5.jpg)

> The rollup should be that all related reporting COA's, Relation Class and the BIS indicator 1 go to LCR DA 1.1.2.1.2.

Comment: MVF is just a fancy option for super-users. They will cause you nothing but trouble, so redesign your table and use queries and new tables to mimic the feature.

Comment: Shouldn't you use something like  `[C73_Outflow]![Reporting CoA_New].VALUE` when referring to a single value in a multivalued field?